# Android OpenGL ES, shape not showing on device, but work fine on emulator?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have follow the tutorial from the android team, showing how to create simple triangle using OpenGL. Here is a [link](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment) to the tutorial. Everything work fine on both android devices and emulator until i get to the part with applying [projection](https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/projection).

Once i change the string **vertexShaderCode** to:

```
private val vertexShaderCode =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
        "}"
```

The triangle is not displayed on my android devices which are Huawei Y2 with Android 6.0 (API 23) and SONY with Android 4.4.4. Any idea why this is happening, I suspect that somehow adding the camera view changes the position of the triangle somewhere outside the viewport. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar display problems on different devices. You can try increasing the value of 'far' in frustumM() method:

```
Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far)
```

Increasing value of this parameter solved the problem for me.

In general, for frustum you can use different parameter values for portrait and landscape orientations like:

```
protected val aspect = widthScreen.toFloat() / heightScreen.toFloat()
...
private fun setPerspectiveProjection() {
    var left = -1.0f; var right = 1.0f
    var bottom = -1.0f; var top = 1.0f
    val near = 1.0f; val far = 145.0f
    if (widthScreen < heightScreen) { // portrait orientation 
        bottom /= aspect
        top /= aspect
    } else { // landscape orientation
        left *= aspect
        right *= aspect
    }
    Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far)
}
```

Comment: I did increase the 'far' argument but with no success, everything else was the same for me. Then i tried changing the the 'near' argument to 1f and it fixed by problem.  
Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1f, 1f, 1f, 7f)

As I suspected, the problem was with the projection matrix, thank to your clue i manage to fix it, so one BIG THANKS from me!!!

Comment: @slaviboy My pleasure. Yes, it’s better if the near and far values have some margin. In general, for frustum you can use different parameter values for portrait and landscape orientations. Added to the answer.